# How can I use greenplum pxf foreign table to insert data to the sql server?

Tags: sql-server, greenplum

When I try to insert data by using pxf foreign table, I got this problem

postgres=# insert into test values(1);
psql: ERROR:  remote component error (500) from '127.0.0.1:5888':  Type  Exception Report   Message  java.io.DataInputStream cannot be cast to [B   Description  The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.   Exception   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.DataInputStream cannot be cast to [B (libchurl.c:967)  (seg0 172.16.100.109:6000 pid=28756) (libchurl.c:967)

execute sql on sqlserver

```
create database test
go 

use test
go

create schema alice
go

create table alice.student
(
    id   int,
    name varchar,
    age  int
)
go
```

execute sql on greenplum

```
CREATE EXTENSION pxf_fdw ;


DROP SERVER sqlserv_server cascade;

CREATE SERVER sqlserv_server FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER jdbc_pxf_fdw OPTIONS (
    jdbc_driver 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
    db_url 'jdbc:sqlserver://172.16.100.109:1433;databaseName=test;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;',
    batch_size '10000',
    fetch_size '2000'
);

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR mxadmin SERVER sqlserv_server OPTIONS ( user 'sa' , pass 'Aa123456');


CREATE FOREIGN TABLE foreign_sqlserver (
    id int4,
    name varchar(20) ,
    age int4
)
SERVER sqlserv_server
OPTIONS (resource 'alice.student');

insert into foreign_sqlserver values(1,'alice',11),(2,'bob',20);
psql: ERROR:  remote component error (500) from '127.0.0.1:5888':  Type  Exception Report   Message  java.io.DataInputStream cannot be cast to [B   Description  The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.   Exception   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.DataInputStream cannot be cast to [B (libchurl.c:967)  (seg1 172.16.100.109:6001 pid=12562) (libchurl.c:967)
```

pxf-service.log paste blow

```
2023-03-27 13:08:37.0736 ERROR tomcat-http--8 org.greenplum.pxf.service.bridge.WriteBridge - Failed to close bridge resources: java.io.DataInputStream cannot be cast to [B
2023-03-27 13:18:24.0044 ERROR tomcat-http--13 org.greenplum.pxf.service.rest.WritableResource - Exception: totalWritten so far 9999 to alice.student
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.DataInputStream cannot be cast to [B
        at org.greenplum.pxf.plugins.jdbc.JdbcResolver.decodeOneRowToPreparedStatement(JdbcResolver.java:309)
        at org.greenplum.pxf.plugins.jdbc.writercallable.BatchWriterCallable.call(BatchWriterCallable.java:68)
        at org.greenplum.pxf.plugins.jdbc.JdbcAccessor.writeNextObject(JdbcAccessor.java:247)
        at org.greenplum.pxf.service.bridge.WriteBridge.setNext(WriteBridge.java:78)
        at org.greenplum.pxf.service.rest.WritableResource.stream(WritableResource.java:138)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.greenplum.pxf.service.servlet.SecurityServletFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SecurityServletFilter.java:145)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
        at org.greenplum.pxf.service.servlet.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1201)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:317)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2023-03-27 13:18:24.0045 ERROR tomcat-http--13 org.greenplum.pxf.service.bridge.WriteBridge - Failed to close bridge resources: java.io.DataInputStream cannot be cast to [B
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Writing from Greenplum Database to the External data sources with FDW is still under development. However, you can use external table to achieve the above task.

Steps:

1. Create extension if it's not present.

   create extension pxf;
2. Create a **writable external** table

   create writable external table <TABLE_NAME> ( COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_TYPE) LOCATION('pxf://<EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME>?PROFILE=Jdbc') FORMAT 'custom' (FORMATTER='pxfwritable_export');

For eg:

```
create writable external table w_pg_ext ( id int4 , name varchar(20), age int4) LOCATION('pxf://pgtest?PROFILE=Jdbc') FORMAT 'custom' (FORMATTER='pxfwritable_export');
```

3. Make sure the jdbc-site.xml has the correct entry for driver and username/password.

   $PXF_BASE/servers/default/jdbc-site.xml

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>jdbc.driver</name>
    <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>jdbc.url</name>
    <value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</value>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>jdbc.user</name>
    <value>USER1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>jdbc.password</name>
   <value>PASSWORD</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

4. Insert the data:

   insert into w_pg_ext values(1,'alice',11);

Refer to this link for more:

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/6-2/pxf/jdbc_pxf.html

Hope this helps!

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But when I was executing "create extension pxf;", I got this error.
psql: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/local/matrixdb-4.8.1.enterprise/share/postgresql/extension/pxf.control": No such file or directory

Comment: What's the difference between pxf and pxf_fdw？Should I reinstall pxf？

Comment: Can you provide the pxf installation location? What version of Greenplum and pxf you are using? It should be looking for pxf.control under $GPHOME/share/postgresql/extension and looks like in your case it is looking in some other directory.

Comment: pxf_fdw is the Foreign data wrapper for pxf which is introduced in Greenplum 6 while `pxf` uses external table framework to access the external data sources.

Comment: PXF's version 5.16.1, and the database is based on Greenplum 7.0.0-beta